# How will hdfs choose which copy to delete?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Suppose: I have a hadoop cluster in which each data slide is set to have 3 copies.

One day, a datanode is unplugged (assume data stored inside is fine), and then hdfs will generate new copies for data stored in this node so that data slide still have 3 copies.
But if datanode is plugged in again the next day, some data slide have 4 copies, then hdfs has to delete 1 of 4 copies.

My question is how does hdfs choose the one to delete? randomly? or just delete the newest one (that means the datanode will be cleared)?

Comment: The block locations of the file on the namenode are going to change to point at the "new" third replica. I don't think you can just "re-attach" the old disk, and have the data be correct automatically.

Comment: Hi @3692015, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question: But if Datanode is repaired and starts to work again, some data slide have 4 copies, then HDFS has to delete 1 of 4 copies**

As you mentioned, *In HDFS when any Datanode unplugged balancer will create the lost copy in another node to maintain proper replication factor for blocks*.

Now if we want to include the same/diff node to HDFS, **We do `format` and include the node to cluster**. So, there will not be excessive replicated blocks in the cluster at any point of time.

Comment: @user3692015 : Pls let me know there are any other questions related to it.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the datanode is wiped out when it crashes.So thats the reason in HDFS,the replication is kept to ensure the data availability is always present in case of datanode failure.

Comment: Sorry I am still confused... If the datanode is simply removed from the cluster and then reconnect (plug out/ plug in), will it be a different story?

Comment: It will be same as connecting a new node( depending on the existing configuration are still present in the node) to the hadoop cluster with no data block in it.

Comment: I don't think that will be the case. Since datanode is just reconnected and healthy, If you have not listed in excluded list of the namenode the datanode will happily reconnect to namenode and send its list of blocks when it connects.